# iPhone Simulator - Calendar.sqlitedb

Tags: iphone, ios

I am running the Apple example program, SimpleEKDemo, which is supposed to post event details to the iphone calendar.  After running and posting a few events, I can find the Calendar.sqlitedb in the simulator library on my laptop, but when I view it using SQLite database browser, it is empty, nothing at all in it.  I am running on Simulator 6.1 and this is the folder that I am viewing the Calendar.sqlitedb in.

Any help on why Calendar.sqlitedb is empty?

Comment: Go to your terminal and type ? sqlite3 Calendar.sqlite and then enter .tables, if you don't see your tables, looks like it's probably been erased. Did you make changes to your Core Data entities and did you regenerate the entities ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the Calendar.sqlite database living in the bundle?  Sometimes app developers put an empty sqlite database in the bundle, then copy it over to the app's file directory at first startup, because things in the bundle are read-only.  You may be looking at the wrong one.

Comment: I did not change or copy anything.  I just downloaded and ran the example code from Apples developer website.

Comment: Still no further forward on this.  Any help on this please?